# Have EU, US passports but live in the US: do I have to follow the 90/180 rule?

Tags: visas, schengen, us-citizens, eu-citizens

Title says it all. Polish citizen, but I live in the US; my understanding is I have to use my US passport when I travel (I am a US citizen). But I want to stay more than 90 days. What is the procedure for this?

Comment: You only need the US passport when you enter (and exit) the US, in any other case it is your choice, also when going to the EU, i.e. you can just use your Polish passport there and stay longer than the 90 days as you wish.

Comment: You can stay in both places as long as you wish!!  Simply use passport A when going to country A.  No need to even mention the other one. Enjoy!

Comment: @JoeBlow Thanks, I appreciate your kind tone! (A lot of people on SE are a bit abrasive :)).

Comment: @RenéG, we get plenty of questions which sound like "they denied my visa, that's unfair" without details about the case. Those tend to get curt replies. You had all relevant information, that makes a difference. BTW, it seems you should read up on your rights as an EU citizen -- you can travel to the EU, work there, vote in local elections if you live there, get expedited visa for your dependents even if they're not EU citizens, etc.

Comment: Even if you enter an EU country with your US passport (which you shouldn't, but mistakes happen) you can still stay as an EU citizen. The fact that you entered using the wrong document doesn't change the fact that your enjoy freedom of movement in the EU (as do your family members when they travel with you).

Comment: Also be absolutely certain that you get both passports for all of your children.

Comment: @JoeBlow this actually seems not to be so important in my experience.

Comment: Hi phoogster!  I'm not sure of the context in which you mean; but; if you have any children who can get EU passports, a central issue in life is to be sure you secure those EU passports for them. If you have to (say) live in a euro nation for a year or two to do that, do it!  Almost as important, if you can get them US passports, in general do that. And then if you can get them any others, do that.